# Flask permanently redirects to /index after raising RequestRedirect('index')

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

So I am using flask 0.9 with python 2.7.  In an attempt to be sneaky without actually understanding what I'm doing, I messed up my url routing.

I am using flask-admin to whip up a quick interface.  Here is what I did:

```
from flask.ext.admin import AdminIndexView
from werkzeug.routing import RequestRedirect

class IndexView(AdminIndexView):
def is_accessible(self):
    if current_user.is_authenticated and current_user.has_role('admin'):
        return True
    else:
        raise RequestRedirect('index')
```

My intent was for this to work like return redirect('index') in a flask-view, alas it did not work as planned.  It just made it so /admin ALWAYS routed to /index after the first time it triggered.

So now, after removing the code and changing the raise statement to return False, my applications are still redirecting /admin to /index (even with a completely different app created on a different virtual environment)..

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have your redirect cached by the browser. See here: http://getluky.net/2010/12/14/301-redirects-cannot-be-undon/

Unfortunately, RequestRedirect() exception returns 301 HTTP status code and it will be cached by the browser.

There's a way to do it better:

1. `is_accessible` is used to verify is certain administrative view is visible by the user. If you have more than one view, it will be called for each view and then only visible menu items will be displayed
2. There's `_handle_view` method that you can override. You can see default implementation here: https://github.com/mrjoes/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/base.py#L269

Feel free to return proper redirect with 302 status code instead of doing abort(404).

Comment: Thank you- I thought I was going crazy, I even reinstalled python; who knows how long it would have taken me to look at the browser cache!  And thank you for pointing me to _handle_view, that does what I was trying to do, a global redirect for non-admin users.  Now that I think of it, I suppose a 404 is more secure as it doesn't hint that the url is valid.  Thanks!

Comment: For debugging i found the icognito mode of Chrome to be useful since it doesn't cache any redirects.